# Groups of integers with equal sums, equal sums of squares, equal sums of cubes....

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, sums-of-squares

The following three groups of 6 numbers have equal sums, sums of squares, sums of cubes,... up to fifth powers. How would one go about finding such groups?

784 134
17  901
342 576

12  906
596 322
769 149

684 234
917 1
226 692

Trying to relate this to Newton's identities for sums of roots I have noticed that, when the numbers are taken as roots of polynomials, the polynomials produced are identical up to a constant:

$x^6 - 2754 x^5 + 2845537 x^4 - 1356302772 x^3 + 292772763028 x^2 - 23245284585024 x + 316988249001984$

$x^6 - 2754 x^5 + 2845537 x^4 - 1356302772 x^3 + 292772763028 x^2 - 23245284585024 x + 239069505576384$

$x^6 - 2754 x^5 + 2845537 x^4 - 1356302772 x^3 + 292772763028 x^2 - 23245284585024 x + 22953865281984$

What is going on here?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: An old but still valuable resource on this sort of problem is Gloden, Mehrgradige Gleichungen.

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients of a monic polynomial can be expressed as functions of the sums of the powers of the roots. And in this case the sums of the powers of the roots are all equal. So the coefficients are equal. (The constant terms are not equal because they involve the sum of the *sixth* powers of the roots, which are not equal.)

Take as an example the polynomial
$$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-(a+b+c)x^2+(ab+bc+ca)x-abc$$
The coefficient of $x^2$ is $-(a+b+c)$.

The coefficient of $x$ is $ab+bc+ca=\frac12((a+b+c)^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2))$.

And the constant term is $-abc=-\frac16(a+b+c)^3+\frac12(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2)-\frac13(a^3+b^3+c^3)$.

Comment: How could more groups be found? Say, if I wanted to look for groups of 8 numbers with equal sums up to the seventh power?